# WPF Exclusive mode

Tags: wpf, video

Is it possible to run a WPF application in exclusive mode - where it owns the entire screen?  I want to do full screen video playback.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `WindowStyle` to `None` and maximize then you will take over the full screen - including task bar. But then you have to implement your own window chrome.

Comment: That's not really the same thing though.  Sure that displays my app in the full screen, but it's not the same as exclusive mode where the application owns the screen and nothing else can draw.  I'm talking aobut how video games do it, where they may even display at a different resolution.

Comment: For that, I believe you need to use DirectX directly.